# Why does Jquery remove() remove overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, overlay

I am trying to create an own overlay since the exact same bug occurred on the overlay plugin.
What I am trying to do is, if someone clicks on an element with the class `overlay` an overlay opens and loads the content of the `href` attribute inside the overlay. When this overlay is closed it is supposed to be deleted (using `remove()` here) but it isn't. Instead if I open another (or even the same) overlay it shows the old one behind.
How can I prevent this?

```
// Overlay for editing
$(".st_overlay[href]").click(function(e){
var url = $(this).attr('href');
$("body").append('<div display="none" class="st_modal"><div class="inner"></div><span class="close">x</span></div>');
$(".st_modal .inner").load(url);
$(".st_modal").fadeIn(500);
});

// Overlay functions
$(".st_modal .close").click(function(e){
$(".st_modal").fadeOut(500);
setTimeout( function(){
$(".st_modal").remove();
}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback function after the fadeout has been completed.

```
$(".st_modal .close").click(function(e){
 $(".st_modal").fadeOut(500, function() {
  $(this).remove();
 });
});
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are attaching the overlay close callback only once, but dynamically injecting the overlays, and after injections you are not attaching them. So either you have to attach to them after injection like this -

```
// Overlay for editing
$(".st_overlay[href]").click(function(e){
var url = $(this).attr('href');
$("body").append('<div display="none" class="st_modal"><div class="inner"></div><span class="close">x</span></div>');
$(".st_modal .inner").load(url);
$(".st_modal").fadeIn(500, function(){
        // Overlay functions
        $(".st_modal .close").click(function(e){
        $(".st_modal").fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout( function(){
         $(".st_modal").remove();
        }, 500);
      });
    });
});

// Overlay functions
$(".st_modal .close").click(function(e){
$(".st_modal").fadeOut(500);
setTimeout( function(){
$(".st_modal").remove();
}, 500);
});
```

or use event delegation so that your dynamically added overlay get the event -

```
// Overlay functions
    $('body').delegate(".st_modal .close", 'click', function(e){
    $(".st_modal").fadeOut(500);
    setTimeout( function(){
    $(".st_modal").remove();
    }, 500);
    });
```